# How to continuously poll a button that I created using scene2d

Tags: java, libgdx

I am attempting to create four buttons that act like a D-pad on the screen. I created the buttons using scene2d, organizing them in a table. I understand how to add a listener that fires once one of the buttons has been clicked, but I want to be able to do something, such as move a character as long as the button is held down. I tried the code below and was getting a null pointer exception. Any thoughts on what I might be able to do? Thank you.

```
public void render() {
    stage.act(Math.min(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(), 1 / 30f));
    stage.draw();
    if (up_button.isPressed()){
        // do something, such as move a character up
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into ActorGestureListener.  Perhaps you can test longPress() against a timer.

[ActorGestureListener](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/utils/ActorGestureListener.html)